# Как правильно писать длинные строковые константы?

Tags: java

Интересует случай многострочных констант при переносе со строки на строку. Собственно сейчас делаю так

```
String query = "SELECT city" +
        "FROM cities " +
        "WHERE city='Moscow'";
```

Comment: Странно, что у тебя запросы к бд - константы

Comment: А насчет многострочный - так это просто удобная форма для чтения и просто синтаксис переноса и вообще не тем ты интересуешься....

Comment: @Gorets, почему странно? Может у человека есть на то весомая причина =)

Comment: Не заморачивайтесь, пишите плюсы

Comment: Не заморачивайтесь и пишите в одну строку :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

раньше так делал:

```
    private static final String SELECT_DUMMY = "" +
            "SELECT * AS TITLE FROM DUAL" ;

    private static final String LIST_ACCOUNTS = "" + 
            "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS" ;

    private static final String GET_USER_PREFERENCES = "" + 
            "SELECT p.* " + 
            "FROM USER_PREFERENCES up, USERS u" +
            "WHERE up.user_id = u.id" +
            "AND u.login_id = ?";
```

преимущество в том что запрос выглядит практически так же как и в IDE для СУБД (toad/sql developer), большую часть правок можно делать прямо в коде. минус же в том, что неудобно копировать запрос для редактирования в IDE (копируется в месте служебными символами языка для формирования строки), лечится выводом констант в sys out.

p.s.

> раньше так делал

сейчас широко используются ORM фреймворки, поэтому хардкод запросов в константах выглядит как минимум странновато

Comment: Для чего ""+ в начале?

Comment: @Russtam: Для сохранения форматирования, конечно. Прикиньте, как бы выглядело без этого.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще "плюсовать" строки при помощи "+" если составных строк больше двух - не правильный подход. Почему можете почитать например [тут](http://www.javaportal.ru/java/articles/stringvsstrbf.html). 
Попробуйте использовать для таких случаев class StringBuffer. Пример:

```
String query = new StringBuffer()
    .append("SELECT city ")
    .append("FROM cities ")
    .append("WHERE city='Moscow'")
    .toString();
```

Comment: Просто к слову,
String smth = "SELECT city " + "FROM cities " + "WHERE city='Moscow'";
компилятор оптимизирует под Ваш код. Если же будет цикл - не оптимизирует.

Comment: Использовать StringBuffer вместо StringBuilder в однопоточном алгоритме тоже не правильный подход.

Comment: Согласен, IronVbif. Классы StringBuilder и StringBuffer являются "близнецами". Основным и единственным отличием StringBuilder от StringBuffer является потокобезопасность последнего. Если необходимости в ней нет, то правильней использовать StringBuilder (он немного быстрее), но нельзя забывать о том, что он непотокобезопасный

Comment: Следует только помнить, что все эти лишние слова имеют смысл только для .append() в цикле (а new StringBuffer/Builder и .toString вне этого цикла).

Comment: мне вот интересно, все отписавшиеся выше реально думают что стрингбилдер спасет ситуацию с перфомансом при обьявлении одной строковой константы ? вы действительно обьявляете запросы в локальных переменных ?

Comment: @jmu, мой комментарий, очевидно, общего характера. 

Кстати, не думаю, что @javax задал вопрос с целью улучшения производительности программы.

Comment: @jmu весь этот ответ и комментарии про сложение строк, а не про запросы =) Думаю все знают про PreparedStatement.

Comment: то что мой комментарий отклоняется от темы вопроса вы все хором заметили, а то что ответ - нет /* no comments */

Comment: на сколько я понял влпрос был как разбить длинную строку на несколько (чтобы читать можно было без скрола, например). Это можно  реализовать, как выяснелось, с помощью "+" и с помощью специальных классов. Я бы выбраз второй способ.

Comment: @pirateweter, это чтобы программа пострашней выглядела ?

Comment: @avp, ага, чтобы всякие боялись там что-то менять

Answer (score 2):

Я лично пишу так:

```
String sql = "" //
            + "select count(TASK_FOR_DATE_ID) " //
            + "from CO.TASK_FOR_DATE tfd " //
            + "    join CO.TASK t on (tfd.TASK_ID=t.TASK_ID) " //
            + "where (tfd.START_TIME between ? and ?)";
```

Преимущество в том, что если использовать автоматическое форматирование кода, то строки не скачут туда-сюда.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String WHITE_SPACE = " ";
```

Comment: Может проще: 

    public static final String WHITE_SPACE=new StringBuilder().append(Character.SPACE_SEPARATOR).toString();' :))